# Menu display problems using XAMPP

Tags: template, xampp, bootstrap

I am having problems with a Bootstrap template I downloaded [from here: https://colorlib.com/wp/template/magazine/ preview here: https://colorlib.com/preview/#magazine ].

The problem is when I load it in the browser (Firefox/Vivaldi) using a virtual host on XAMPP (local) the menu (mobile also) doesn't display correctly. But when loaded directly in the browser (Firefox/Vivaldi) as a regular file it works fine. (I have uploaded it to a live server and it worked just fine there.) This leads me to believe there is something wrong with my XAMPP set-up. However, I can't see what it would be as I only changed the following files:

```
/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf
/etc/hosts
/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Here are images of the problem:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Anyone have an idea of what is happening? Let me know if more info is necessary.

Comment: Client-side relative URL issue perhaps?

Comment: Please describe the specifics of the problem and include relevant screenshots in your question (rather than linking to an external resource, on which you have overlayed text on the images). Is your server returning the correct mime-types for these resources? Are all the resources loading OK? Do you have the same URL path on the local and production servers? Problems with client-side rendering can be caused by using relative URL paths - depends on your path structure.

Comment: Is there anything in the developer tools message console of firefox when you load the page under XAMP?   Any sort of error messages would be very helpful in solving this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I have decided not to use `.php` file extensions but rather `.html`. That way I don't need to use XAMPP. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because you say you don't need a solution any longer.